# javascript coundown " SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.' "

Tags: javascript

```
 var dateObj = new Date();
                 var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() +1;
                 var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
                 var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
                 var nowhour = dateObj.getHours();
                 var nowday = dateObj.getUTCDate();
                 var hour = "03";
                 var min = "00";

                 var hour2 = "18";
                 var min2 = "00";

                 var hour3 = "21";
                 var min3 = "00";


                if(hour == 03)
                {
                day++;
                }
                document.write(nowhour);
                 newdate = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
                 hourdate = " " + hour + ":" + min;
                 hourdate2 = " " + hour2 + ":" + min3;
                 hourdate3 = " " + hour2 + ":" + min3;
                 $("#bifrost")
                 if(nowhour > hour && day > nowday)
                {
                .countdown(newdate + hourdate, function (event) {$(this).text(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));});
                }else if(nowhour > hour2)
                {
                .countdown(newdate + hourdate2, function (event) {$(this).text(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));});
                }else{
                .countdown(newdate + hourdate3, function (event) {$(this).text(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));});
                }
```

Hello, i wanna make a countdown timer for events. I have 3 different event time,i wanna show up coming event here is my javascript code. 
can anyone help me ?
ps: sorry for my bad english.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: when i run page i get this error. http://prntscr.com/78kdvz

Comment: What is the purpose of the "document.write(nowhour)" in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `countdown` is a global function, you do not need the period before the call, just

```
countdown(parameters ... );
```

If `countdown` is a jquery plugin you have, and you are trying to call it on the jQuery object you created before the if statements, you must do it like this

```
$("#bifrost").countdown(parameters ... );
```

And repeat the jQuery selector in each of your if statements.

Answer (score 1):

There is built in function `setTimeout(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...)`. Please see for examples in [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

`setTimeout(function_to_do, miliseconds to wait)` - will be triggered once;

`setInterval(function_to_do, miliseconds to wait)` - will be triggered periodically.

By the way - function name can't start with dot - and you have three calls to something `.countdown(...` There is you error.